# Deserializing invalid JSON c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object in c#

This is my code:

```
WebResponse responseWtch = httpWReqWtch.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader srWtch = new StreamReader(responseWtch.GetResponseStream()))
{
  string pageWtch = srWtch.ReadToEnd();
  JObject o = JObject.Parse(pageWtch);
  string name = (string)o["id"];
```

Now, the problem that i'm having, is that my response contains multiple '/', which doesn't make it a real json file. Is there a way to get this handled better?

Comment: So should this question be called 'Deserializing invalid JSON' ? Can you give an example of the invalid parts of your JSON?

Comment: Why don't you give us a sample of the JSON?

Comment: _"Is there a way to get this handled better?"_ - yes, sanitize your input. If you want to know how, show the input. @CuongLe another HTTP client (if OP even supports .NET 4.5) is not going to change the resulting data.

Comment: Use `HttpClient` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to manage the JSON data as an object you could skip the deserialization and use the raw text data.

I would suggest that the "best" solution is to fix the malformatted JSON so you can parse it as intended.